# How to get Dbpedia resource in several languages

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

i want for a given dbpedia resource in a source language to get it's equivalent resource in a target language,  i searched to use sparql but i did not find any request to do it..
For Example: For the keyword Car
language source  is en:  http://dbpedia.org/page/Car
and f my language target is french , i want to get http://fr.dbpedia.org/page/Automobile

I want to do that automatically .. there is a solution with sparql or any other tool ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `owl:sameAs` for this and then filter the results to the version of DBpedia you want.

For example:

```
SELECT ?x {
  dbr:Car owl:sameAs ?x.
  FILTER(strstarts(str(?x), "http://fr.dbpedia.org/resource/"))
}
```

This query returns a single result: http://fr.dbpedia.org/resource/Automobile.

Comment: Thank you.. that's what i need

Comment: hello, do you know how to do the same thing using mediawiki api, to get a wikipedia page name iin several languages ??

Comment: @Nad You should ask a new question for that.